# Why sometimes the scala compiler interpret in a different way white spaces and dots

Tags: scala

E.g. If I write this function:

```
def function1() : Unit = {            
 aVar = myList.map { ( s :Something ) => (s.id, s.name) } toList
 function2()
}

def function2() : Unit = {
   //bla
}
```

The compiler complains when calling `function2` saying expecting `Int` but found `Unit`. I just can't figure out where the required `Int` comes from.

Now, if I write `function1` as follows it compiles and works exactly as I was expecting:

```
def function1() : Unit = {            
     aVar = myList.map { ( s :Something ) => (s.id, s.name) } toList
     var x = function2()
}
```

Why!!!!???? Just assigning `function2` to a `var` changes the behavior?? In first place `function2` is defined to return `Unit`...

Next it gets more tangled, any of the next two `function1` definitions works perfectly:

```
def function1() : Unit = {            
         aVar = myList.map { ( s :Something ) => (s.id, s.name) }.toList
         function2()
    }

def function1() : Unit = {            
         aVar = (myList.map { ( s :Something ) => (s.id, s.name) } toList)
         function2()
    }
```

It looks like having an space instead a dot sometimes can be dangerous but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using space instead of `.` in scala should be used **preferably** with one parameter function in the following way:

```
myObject itsFunction param
```

Thus, when you type myMap `toList`, the compiler still waiting for a param, and take it from the next line of code, while, when you type `myMap.toList` it doesn't wait for anything and it considers function2 as a independent instruction.
It's quite the same when you assign the result of `function2`to a `var`. As soon as the compiler see the `var` declaration, it understands that the previous statement is closed and don't expect a parameter anymore.

Here, you should wonder what parameter does the compiler expect, as `toList` doesn't need any. Actually, `toList` returns a `List` and `List` has an `apply`method... And that's exactly what the compiler is waiting for: the parameter of `List`'s apply method.

Maybe this REPL session will help you:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 2) toList 0
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

Comment: Ok, so this is valid but is error prone? Why is apply function called behind the scene when using the toList?

Comment: @rsan: Because apply is always called when writing `x()`. And because `xs toList` is interpreted as `xs.toList()` an error is thrown because of missing argument for `toList`.

Comment: Tnx to both. I think the 'preferably' mentioned by Nicolas is the key point here. Something funny is that in almost all examples you find in the web you see the toList, toMap etc with a white space instead a dot. Every day you learn something new :)

Comment: @rsan the problem is that with  you are using **postfix method syntax**, i.e. `myList toList` rather than `myList.toList`. This is discouraged except in DSLs because it can lead to problems such as yours. It will be hidden behind a language flag to prevent abuse when SIP-18 comes into effect.